# What is the proper suffix to change bildungsroman into an adjective?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, suffixes, derivational-morphology, german

In this case I am wondering what suffix would be the best use for bildungsroman when trying to characterize a memoir.

Comment: Can you please give an example that shows how you would like to use this adjective, and what you want it to mean? For example, should it mean "related to a Bildungsroman" or "reminiscent of a Bildungsroman" or "occurring in a Bildungsroman"? Context is always helpful. If you have any ideas that you aren't sure of, or any previous research that you've done, that would also be helpful.

Comment: Lacking any context, the best suffix is a zero suffix. That is, the adjective for *bildungsroman* is *bildungsroman*. (Just like in German itself, by the way. You'd use it as a prefix with no changes.)

Comment: Isn't it the compound adjective 'coming-of-age'? A coming-of-age novel? Oh, I think I got it now: you are wondering whether it should be 'bildungsromantic', or 'bildungsromanesque', or 'bildungsromanced', or other…

Comment: Not that I'd use it, but ... The memoir was *bildungsroman-like* in its structure.  Better would be "like a bildungsroman".  **Bildungs-memoir** is already a coinage.

Comment: Consider "initiatory".

Comment: @RegDwigнt Seriously?  You're unclear on what the question is?  The request is for something like *bildungsromanig*, *bildungsromanisch*, or *bildungsromanlich*; alternatively *bildungsromantic*, *bildungsromanish*, or *bildungsroman-like* (respectively).

Comment: @deadrat yes, I am unclear on what the question is. That is because the question is not clear. You yourself have not answered it. You will *not* be able to answer it. The OP is asking for the best suffix. What you have provided are three worst suffixes. Getting you words that do not even exist. Read my comment again. At least I actually gave him a honest answer. While asking him for more context. Which is what we always ask of everyone. A half-assed "gimme best word" one-liner is not clear by definition. Never has been, never will be. It is as unclear as all heck. Yes, seriously.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Sorry, but this is the kind of dismissive attitude that ill serves this site.  And you can stop telling me what I can and can't do.  Perhaps there is no "best" answer, but I wasn't aware that moderatorship granted you the power to determine what suffixes are the "worst."  This is a question about how to adapt a loan word.  If you need more context, fine, but stop trying  to pretend that there's a mystery here.

Comment: @deadrat I am not pretending there is any kind of mystery here. Quite the opposite indeed. I expressly stated both German and English would use no suffix. You come along and spout utter nonsense about "bildungsromanig, bildungsromanisch, or bildungsromanlich". The top and only answer agrees with me. Four people agree with the top answer. I am not sure why you'd think that it's my moderatorship that grants me the power to determine that your words do not exist. That is even more nonsense. I am just providing an informed answer. You are the one who's looking at my diamond.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I am looking at your diamond because you've decided to close the question.  Your stated reason is that the question isn't clear.   Is *mystery* too strong? And you've provided a comment, not an answer.  Only rogermue has done that (although one can only wonder how he was able to do so without the required clarity).   If you don't like my suggestion of German suffixes, then downvote my answer.  Oh, wait.  I forgot. I can't answer.  But never mind; it looks like user165761 is gone.  I guess your work here is done.

Answer (score 4):

I think it would not be a satisfying wordformation if you add an English suffix to a German noun such as bildungsroman. Even in German I would not try to coin such an adjective formation. I advise formulating your idea without an adjective derived from bildungsroman.